# Downloading from camera to computer running Window XP

Tags: canon, windows, wireless

Is there a way to use my Canon EOS RP's wireless function to download images to a computer running Windows XP?

Canon's Image Transfer Utility works only on Windows 7 and later, but maybe there's a way to just connect Windows Explorer with the camera that I'm not seeing?

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Comment: Would learning that MS stopped licensing XP in 2008, 13 years ago, provide "enlightenment"?

Comment: Hi, Ray. Wait, what?! Stopped licensing?! <g> No, actually, I learned that way back in 2019. Let's assume I have still have some compelling reason to use XP in this application. Thanks.

Comment: Relevant info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol). But if your OS is old, your hardware is even older...?

Comment: Can't you remove the memory card and use a card reader? Or you are interested specifically in the WiFi, and not just in some/fastest way to transfer the photos?

Comment: Hi. I'm interested specifically in the Wifi. I can pull the card and put it into a card reader attached to the XP computer, and that works fine. I'd just like to see whether I can get WiFi going on this XP box. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Note that this is a possibility only as I have no experience with what I am about to suggest*</sup>

As you discovered Canon's Image Transfer Utility is only supported in Windows 7.  However there seems to be technology included in Windows XP that could allow for the functionality that you are looking for.

From googling some random terms about image transfer from cameras to Windows XP, I discovered [Picture Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol)

> Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP) is a protocol developed by the
> International Imaging Industry Association to allow the transfer of
> images from digital cameras to computers and other peripheral devices
> without the need of additional device drivers. The protocol has been
> standardized as ISO 15740.

From that same link:

> A number of protocols have been developed that extend PTP. PTP/IP,
> developed by FotoNation and first implemented in a round of Wi-Fi
> digital cameras by Nikon, Canon, and Eastman Kodak, allows data
> transfer over any IP-based network.

And that sounded promising, but the article also had a link to [Windows Image Acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition) that was first included in Windows ME.

> Windows Image Acquisition (WIA; sometimes also called Windows Imaging
> Architecture) is a proprietary Microsoft driver model and application
> programming interface (API) for Microsoft Windows Me and later Windows
> operating systems that enables graphics software to communicate with
> imaging hardware such as scanners, digital cameras, and digital video
> equipment. It was first introduced in 2000 as part of Windows Me, and
> continues to be the standard imaging device and API model through
> successive Windows versions. It is implemented as an on-demand service
> in Windows XP and later Windows operating systems.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition)

This inspired me to search for WIA drivers for XP, and then I hit pay dirt!  An article from Canon themselves: [How to install the WIA driver for my camera](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART125258)

> WIA stands for Windows Imaging Acquisition. The Windows Imaging
> Acquisition package is an integral part of Windows Me and Windows XP
> (the WIA features are not available in Windows 98 or Windows 2000).
> Using a WIA Driver (similar in function to the Twain Driver) with
> Windows Me or Windows XP provides two advantages: (1) when you connect
> your camera to the computer, it will give you the option of download
> pictures using the Windows Scanners and Cameras Wizard, which will
> start automatically in Windows Me, and (2) your camera will show up in
> Windows Explorer as another storage device on the "tree" on the left
> side of the screen. It will show a camera icon and will be displayed
> below your hard drive and CDROM drive. As such, you will be able to
> see a list of the image files stored in your camera, and you may
> transfer them out as you would from any drive.

This seems to be exactly the functionality that you are looking for.  However as previously stated I have no idea if this will actually work, and how you get the drivers onto your XP box etc.

Comment: This is fantastic. Although, as you know, things don't always work as we hope they will. Use of these WIA drivers seems to refer to transferring images over a cable, which Canon supports today, although again, only with software that I cannot install on XP. I will get a cable and see whether your research works. Thank you.

Comment: @user533604 That's why I said I had no experience in it!  I didn't see that part about cables, but I didn't read any further into it after I saw that Canon had WIA drivers for XP - I just assumed that they worked over Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why the RP would care what WiFi is is connected to. Not being close to an XP, and few of us are, can you start a WiFi connection on the XP and link the RP to it.
see: https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+xp+wifi+setup&cvid=9982b734d6dd4b69a95a2ac054cfedb7&aqs=edge.3.0j69i57j0l5.12047j0j1&pglt=929&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=W000

That may help.

Given the age of the OS, I expect the link to be slowww. To unbearable, given the size of the RP images.

Make sure that this XP box DOES NOT CONNECT to the Internet as it is vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Thanks again. That link just talks about basic XP WiFi, which I already understand. I was hoping for a way to "find" the camera from the XP computer. Seems that might be the way to do it, since the Image Transfer Utility doesn't support XP. Hmm. Also, maybe there's an archived older Transfer Utility that *did* support XP? I haven't been able to find one. --SD